# Распознается только размер рамки таблицы почему не распознается цвет и тип рамки?

Tags: html, css

```
            do   
    {

    echo  "<table border='3px' dashed green><tr><td>".$row['fio_student' ]."</td>";
    echo  "<td>".$row['groupst']."</td>";
    echo  "<td>".$row['starosta']."</td>";
    echo  "<td>".$row['info_st']."</td></table>";
    }
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Мухи отдельно, котлеты отдельно*". Не нужно без крайней необходимости, прописывать стили внутри тегов. Для таких целей создается CSS-файл. А если уж такая крайняя необходимость и существует, то это надо делать соответствующим способом:

```
<table style="border: 3px dashed green;">
```

или же "дедушкиным способом"

```
<table border="3" bordercolor="green">
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in....эх не нравится

Comment: а стиль никак не воспринимается
<STYLE type="text/css">
table { border="3px" color: blue }
</STYLE>

Comment: Ну так  закоментируйте двойные кавычки или одинарные поставьте:

    <table style='border: 3px dashed green;'>
    // или 
    <table style=\"border: 3px dashed green;\">

И в стилях:

    <style type="text/css"> 
    table { border: 3px solid blue; } 
    </style>

P.S. Почему у меня дурное предчуствие, что учитесь вы на уроках Попова?

Comment: спасибо,
вы угадали